# I can't setcookie "headers already sent"

Tags: php, setcookie

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912029/warning-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent-by-error)
>   [setcookie, Cannot modify header information - headers already sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658083/setcookie-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent)

I have this code to set cookie :

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE["CorkIU"])) {
setcookie("CorkIU", 2dd2ee3aUgsvoRye, time()+60*60*24*365, "/");
}
```

I have added this code in layout.php file

The first lines from layout.php file is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<?
    include ("inc/css.php");

if (!isset($_COOKIE["CorkIU"])) {
setcookie("CorkIU", 2dd2ee3aUgsvoRye, time()+60*60*24*365, "/");
}

?>
<head>
<title>Welcome To Example</title>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<link href="style/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
```

and here is the error :

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/ex/public_html/template/layout.php:4) in /home/ex/public_html/template/layout.php on line 8
```

Comment: Plenty of duplicates to help you debug your code.

Comment: Cookies must be set **before** making any kind of output. But this question has been asked so many times before that even Google knows the answer!

Answer (score 4):

The error tells you everything you need to know:

> headers already sent by (output

Move the call to `setcookie` to before you output any content (which you do here: `<!DOCTYPE html`)

Answer (score 0):

From the **[PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)**:

> setcookie() defines a cookie to be sent along with the rest of the
>   HTTP headers. Like other headers, cookies must be sent before any
>   output from your script (this is a protocol restriction). *This
>   requires that you place calls to this function prior to any output,
>   including  and  tags as well as any whitespace*.